# getting Count(Record) result to a variable in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to capture count of record to a variable but code is not working. Please assist

```
Dim PrevRgAPAC As Integer
   Dim con As New SqlConnection
   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
   Dim rd As SqlDataReader

 con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XXXXXXXXXXX; initial catalog=XXXXXXXXXXXX; Integrated Security=true"
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()

        cmd.CommandText = "select count(record) from tblKPI where user_region='APAC' AND payroll_month='February'"

        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rd.HasRows Then
            rd.Read()
            PrevRgAPAC = rd.Item("exec")

        Else
            MsgBox("Not Found")
        End If
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

```
PrevRgAPAC = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Assuming that `PrevRgAPAC` is the variable in which you want to store the value of count. So your code would look like this:

```
Dim PrevRgAPAC As Int32 = 0
Dim sql As String = "select count(record) from tblKPI where user_region='APAC' AND payroll_month='February'"

Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXXXXXXXX; initial catalog=XXXXXXXXXXXX; Integrated Security=true")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    Try
        conn.Open()
        PrevRgAPAC = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, I see you have altered the conn declaration a bit. Is it necessary to alter this declaration to specifically have count result.

Comment: This is first day on VB.Net and I am developing this for my company so I need to know if the code I used is the correct or the one confirmed by you is the correct one. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: @RajatSharma:- You can use the connection string as you are doing. I just did it in my way. The point was to use the `ExecuteScalar` method

Comment: @RajatSharma:- Also as a good practice you should try to use the `using` statement. It is a recommended.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I will try this now and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Hey Rahul, I want to work with excel files in VB.Net so I have downloaded Nasosoft addin and writing Imports Nasosoft.Documents.Spreadsheets as per the instructions but its not identifying it. Can you please help here.

Comment: @RajatSharma:- I suggest you to ask a  seperate question for that and do provide the details as to what you have tried and what problems you are getting. It will attract more users. Happy to help

Comment: Rahul - I have been blocked from asking questions :(  which is why I am contacting you via comments

Comment: Hi Rahul, now I am able to export data from SQL to excel but it is too slow since its For loop. Can you help me on how I can do it with data tables so export data quickly to excel. thanks